# How to get rid of inflate/deflate errors?

Tags: linux, zlib, configure

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and heasoft 6.29 (latest version) and while configuring a software I get these set of errors,

"/home/prat/heasoft-6.29/heacore/cfitsio/zcompress.c:473: undefined reference to `deflateInit2_' /home/prat/heasoft-6.29/heacore/cfitsio/zcompress.c:486: undefined reference to` deflate'
/home/prat/heasoft-6.29/heacore/cfitsio/zcompress.c:526: undefined reference to `deflateEnd' /home/prat/heasoft-6.29/heacore/cfitsio/zcompress.c:514: undefined reference to` deflateEnd'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

I am running the configure file given by the software team with ./Configure. The internet suggests to install zlib but I already have its latest version. Having a hard time with this. Any lead will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I installed  zlibrary package with ''sudo apt-get install zlib* " and added -lz to each line of the configure file. The compiler could not find the library it required to perform all those functions (inflate, deflate etc.) all I had to do was give a link to that with -lz.

So turns out the issue was not with the heasoft.